# Google Scripts Exceeded Maximum Execution Time

Tags: google-apps-script

I was running my google scripts code which should only take around 40 seconds to complete in the script. The thing is that I thought the limits of google script execution is 6 minutes according to the google script limitation documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

But my script actually terminates way before it at around 30s...

> [17-03-06 15:22:15:806 PST] Execution failed: Exceeded maximum execution time ?[32.134 seconds total runtime]

Could I get some guidance as to why this is happening? I was running some other add-ons earlier on another sheet... but I closed them and they shouldn't be doing anything

Comment: You might want to report this on [Apps Script Issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)  I doubt you'll get an answer here.  And you could post about this in the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Well, there is currently an [enhancement issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=966) about the 5 minute maximum script execution time in the Apps Script. You can try to check this if it can help you. Also, try to check this [guide](https://ctrlq.org/code/20016-maximum-execution-time-limit) on how you can prevent your Google Scripts from Exceeding the Maximum Execution Time Limit.